# Displaying Output Not as Expected

Tags: java, io

For the following program i am expecting output as

```
Enter any Value : 3
You Entered 3
```

But i am not getting output, instead in output java is expecting some input without displaying "Enter any Value". If i  enter any value then it will display the output as

```
3
Enter any value : You Entered 3.
```

Here is my code:

```
    import java.io.*;
    // System.in is an object of InputStream - byte stream

    class ConsoleInputDemo{
        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
            BufferedReader consoleInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); // This will convert byte stream to character stream
            PrintWriter consoleOutput = new PrintWriter(System.out); 

            consoleOutput.println("Enter any Value : ");
            int c= consoleInput.read();
            consoleOutput.write("You entered " + c);
            consoleInput.close();
            consoleOutput.close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: you might be not getting 3 if you enter 3, you will get ASCII value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`consoleOutput.println` didn't print anything until it `close()`. Use

```
 System.out.println("Enter any Value :  ")
```

instead of

```
consoleOutput.println("Enter any Value : ");
```

Or close `consoleOuput` if you want to view the text.

```
 consoleOutput.print("Enter any Value : ");
 consoleOutput.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print("Enter any Value :  ");
    try {
        int c=Integer.parseInt(new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(System.in))).readLine());
        System.out.println("Entered Character: " +c);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This simple code might help you achieve your requirement.`read()` will just give you ascii value so I preffer using `readline()` method to get actual values. Offcourse it will return string so just parse it to get integer.